# Join 4 tables and update in 5th table MySql

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to join 4 tables and update 5th table

```
INSERT INTO relation_table(cid,pid,liid,lnid,lgid,l_key)
SELECT  a.cid,
        a.pid,
        b.liid,
        c.lnid,
        d.lang,
        md5("a.cid a.pid b.liid c.lnid d.lang")
FROM links a
        INNER JOIN links_table b
            ON a.lurl = b.lurl
        INNER JOIN lname_table c
            ON a.lname = c.lname
        INNER JOIN lang_table d
            ON a.lang = d.lang
where a.lurl = "google"
```

Master table links has all the values in it and other 3 tables are sub tables with there own id + value which i am using to join then and update there id in relation table.

EDIT

sorry i did not mention error its md5 [Err] 1062 - Duplicate entry '78527d845cc56e5d28e019d22565f2d7' for key 'l_key' when i am trying to add 1 record its ok but with 2nd record its not working, b.liid is different in 2nd one ... but still its md5 is same as 1st one .
its not working, i am not sure if this is right way to do it.

Please help

Comment: I don't see any syntax errors in the query.  Can you let us know what the exact problem is?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry i did not mention error its md5 [Err] 1062 - Duplicate entry '78527d845cc56e5d28e019d22565f2d7' for key 'l_key' when i am trying to add 1 record its ok but with 2nd record its not working, b.liid is different in 2nd one ... but still its md5 is same as 1st one .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently always passing the *same* string to the `md5()` function.  For the first record you `INSERT` there is no problem, but as soon as you try inserting a second record you get the duplicate entry error.

```
md5("a.cid a.pid b.liid c.lnid d.lang")
```

I believe you instead intended to build a unique string based on the 5 identifiers.  You could try something along these lines instead:

```
md5(CONCAT(a.cid, a.pid, b.liid, c.lnid, d.lang))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the md5() function:

```
md5("a.cid a.pid b.liid c.lnid d.lang")
```

This way the md5 hash of the fixed "a.cid a.pid b.liid c.lnid d.lang" string will be generated. Use

```
md5(concat(a.cid, a.pid, b.liid, c.lnid, d.lang))
```

instead. Also, you should consider if your query could return the same set of ids multiple times. If yes, then use the `distinct` keyword in the select.